# Different natural items [python]

Tags: python

**N** - number *1≤n≤10^9*.
Need to find the maximum number **k** for which **N** can be provided as the amount of **k** of different natural items.

```
For example: if n = 3 then '1 2' , if n = 4 then '1 3', if n = 5 then '2 3', if n = 6 then '1 2 3' and etc.
```

How to make it?
I tried by means of lists, but anything it is impossible :-(
Prompt, please!

code example

```
def mu(n,l,i):
    #print(n,l,i)
    #su = 0
    #h = 0
    if (n>0):
        if i not in l:
            l.append(i)
            s = i
            if (s >=n):
                le=len(l)
                return l
            mu(n-1,l,i+1)
    return l
l=[]
n= 6
x=mu(n,l,1)
l=x
le=len(l)
m = [] #new list
#l.reverse()
for j in range(0,le-1):
    for g in range(1,le):
       print(l[j],l[g])
print(l)
```

Result:

1 2 3

Comment: Could you also show us what you have tried (source code, logic/reasoning...)? This will help us understand your problems better.

Comment: def mu(n,l,i):
    #print(n,l,i)
    su = 0
    h = 0
    if (n>0):
        if i not in l:
            l.append(i)
            s = i
            if (s >=n):
                le=len(l)
                return l
            mu(n-1,l,i+1)
    return l
l=[]
n= 6
x=mu(n,l,1)
l=x
le=len(l)
m = [] #new list
#l.reverse()
for j in range(0,le):
    for g in range(1,le-1):
        #print(l[j],l[g])
print(l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l=[]
n = int(input())
s = 0
k = 0
i = 1
while s<n:
    s = s+i
    if (s<n):
        l.append(i)
        k = k + 1
        i = i+1
    elif (s>n):
        l.remove(s-n)
        l.append(i)
    elif (s==n):
        l.append(i)
        k = k + 1
print(k)
for i in range(0,k):
    print(l[i],end=' ')
```

I found a decision. Thanks to everybody. Your help was not vain !

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I would suggest coming at this from the other end; for a given `k`, what is the least possible `N`?

---

We are looking for the largest possible value of `k` such that `1 + 2 + 3 ... + k <= N`.

The sum of the arithmetic series `1 .. k` is `k * (k + 1) / 2`; setting this equal to `N` (the limiting case) and rearranging, we get the quadratic equation `k**2 + k - 2*N == 0`.

Solving by quadratic formula gives `k = (-1 +/- sqrt(1 + 8*N)) / 2`. We only want the positive root, which simplifies to `k = sqrt(2*N + 0.25) - 0.5`; then `k` must be an integer, so we round down to find the greatest possible integer value of k.

The list of values may be non-unique - for most values of N, there are many ways to do it - but we can always find a solution in the form `1 + 2 + ... (k - 1)` plus a final corrective value `N - (k - 1) * k / 2`.

This can be implemented as

```
def max_k(n):
    return int((2*n + 0.25) ** 0.5 - 0.5)

def make_l(n, k):
    l = list(range(1, k))
    sum_so_far = (k - 1) * k // 2
    last_value = n - sum_so_far
    l.append(last_value)
    return l

def mu(n, l, i):
    k = max_k(n)
    l = make_l(n, k)
    return k, l

def main():
    for n in range(1, 23):
        k, l = mu(n, None, None)
        l_str = " ".join(str(i) for i in l)
        print("{:>2}   {:>2}   {}".format(n, k, l_str))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which produces

```
 1    1   1
 2    1   2
 3    2   1 2
 4    2   1 3
 5    2   1 4
 6    3   1 2 3
 7    3   1 2 4
 8    3   1 2 5
 9    3   1 2 6
10    4   1 2 3 4
11    4   1 2 3 5
12    4   1 2 3 6
13    4   1 2 3 7
14    4   1 2 3 8
15    5   1 2 3 4 5
16    5   1 2 3 4 6
17    5   1 2 3 4 7
18    5   1 2 3 4 8
19    5   1 2 3 4 9
20    5   1 2 3 4 10
21    6   1 2 3 4 5 6
22    6   1 2 3 4 5 7
```

which clearly shows the structure of the problem.

Comment: It is here required to decide by means of avid algorithm.

Comment: the k elements of sequence of natural numbers are different, i.e. can not be 3+3 = 6, it must be 1+2+3

Comment: I looked your algorithm. He works not so, as needed 
For example: 
if n = 5 then [2,3]
if n = 8 then [1,3,4]
if n = 9 then [2,3,4]
if n = 11 then [1,2,3,5]
if n = 12 then [1,2,4,5]
...
if n = 20 then [2,3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, we would head towards the largest value of k in 1+2+...k <= N. For example, let's take 30. The largest would be 1+2+3+..+7= 28. (where k = 7).

We know this **is** the **largest** k (for 28), because if we had a larger k than 7, like 8, then one of the numbers from 1..7 must be subtracted from, resulting in a duplicated number.

We can also proceed to say that 7 is the largest k for 30, because the number that is left, which is 2, will NOT add to our maximum k, as it is already repeated, and will be consumed by the 7 (resulting in `1 2 3 4 5 6 9` as the optimal choice).

Here's an implementation:

```
for number in range(1,51):
   res = []
   i=0
   sigma = 0

   while(sigma<=number):
      i+=1
      sigma+=i
      if(sigma <= number):
          res += [i]

   res[len(res)-1] += number-sum(res)

   print(number, end='. result: ')
   print(res, end='  k=')
   print(len(res))
```

I tested the code for all values 1-51, and here are the results:

```
 1. result: [1]  k=1
 2. result: [2]  k=1
 3. result: [1, 2]  k=2
 4. result: [1, 3]  k=2
 5. result: [1, 4]  k=2
 6. result: [1, 2, 3]  k=3
 7. result: [1, 2, 4]  k=3
 8. result: [1, 2, 5]  k=3
 9. result: [1, 2, 6]  k=3
 10. result: [1, 2, 3, 4]  k=4
 11. result: [1, 2, 3, 5]  k=4
 12. result: [1, 2, 3, 6]  k=4
 13. result: [1, 2, 3, 7]  k=4
 14. result: [1, 2, 3, 8]  k=4
 15. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  k=5
 16. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]  k=5
 17. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]  k=5
 18. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 8]  k=5
 19. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 9]  k=5
 20. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]  k=5
 21. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  k=6
 22. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]  k=6
 23. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8]  k=6
 24. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]  k=6
 25. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]  k=6
 26. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11]  k=6
 27. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12]  k=6
 28. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  k=7
 29. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]  k=7
 30. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]  k=7
 31. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10]  k=7
 32. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11]  k=7
 33. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12]  k=7
 34. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 13]  k=7
 35. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 14]  k=7
 36. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  k=8
 37. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]  k=8
 38. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]  k=8
 39. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11]  k=8
 40. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12]  k=8
 41. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 13]  k=8
 42. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14]  k=8
 43. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15]  k=8
 44. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 16]  k=8
 45. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  k=9
 46. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]  k=9
 47. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11]  k=9
 48. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12]  k=9
 49. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13]  k=9
 50. result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14]  k=9
```

Comment: How to accumulate a sum it is correct, except collisions 
I have a list. If N = 6, that turns out next list [1,2,3,4]
From him it is necessary to delete 4 element, as a sum of first 3-ех is already equal to 6.

Yet case. There is N=5, then a next list turns out [1,2,3]
From him it is necessary to delete the first element

Yet case. There is N=7, then a next list turns out  [1,2,3,4]
from him it is necessary to delete a 3-ex element (as though so)
 
I can not to the logician program :-(

Comment: Here's my implementation: https://repl.it/BZDd. You just have to make sure to put your overcount checking in right place to not over-sum.

Comment: Your decision interesting, thank you !
But it does not suit

Comment: Yep, I also updated my code if you would like to try it out. And, it is nice that you figured out the algorithm as well! :-)

Comment: -) looked : 

Thank you to you for prompts

Higher added the code that decides my task